# ember js error before page loads

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli

I am trying to upgrade ember application to 3.1.3. On main page load I am getting an error:

```
Could not find module `ember` imported from `ember-truth-helpers/utils/register-helper`
```

I upgraded the version to `"ember-truth-helpers": "2.0.0"` and ran npm install, but it still shows the same error.

Here are the package.json depdendencies.

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
    "ember-ajax": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli": "~3.1.3",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^6.6.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^4.2.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.1",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "4.3.2",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-data": "3.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-maybe-import-regenerator": "^0.1.6",
    "ember-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-source": "3.2.0",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^3.0.0",
    "loader.js": "^4.2.3",
    "animateplus": "1.4.0",
    "body-parser": "1.15.2",
    "connect-restreamer": "1.0.3",
    "crossfilter": "1.3.12",
    "d3": "3.5.11",
    "dc": "2.0.0-beta.20",
    "ember-animatable": "0.1.6",
    "ember-api-actions": "0.0.11",
    "ember-autoresize": "1.3.0",
    "ember-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "1.1.0",
    "ember-browserify": "1.2.2",
    "ember-browsery-stats": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-autoprefixer": "0.5.0",
    "ember-cli-chart": "3.3.2",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-copyable": "0.9.6",
    "ember-cli-flash": "1.3.16",
    "ember-cli-mirage": "^0.4.7",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "3.7.1",
    "ember-cli-nouislider": "^0.13.0",
    "ember-cli-page-object": "^1.8.0",
    "ember-cli-release": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "ember-cli-sass": "5.5.1",
    "ember-cli-selectize": "0.5.12",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "ember-cli-test-recorder": "0.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "ember-cookie-monster": "0.0.2",
    "ember-django-adapter": "1.1.2",
    "ember-href-to": "0.0.11",
    "ember-in-viewport": "2.0.8",
    "ember-light-table": "^1.12.1",
    "ember-modal-dialog": "^2.3.0",
    "ember-moment": "7.7.0",
    "ember-network": "0.1.0",
    "ember-polyfill-for-tests": "0.2.0",
    "ember-power-select": "^1.8.5",
    "ember-responsive": "^2.0.5",
    "ember-route-action-helper": "2.0.6",
    "ember-shepherd": "2.1.3",
    "ember-simple-auth": "1.3.0",
    "ember-slack-search-input": "^1.0.6",
    "ember-sortable": "1.8.2",
    "ember-tag-search-input": "0.6.0",
    "ember-tether": "0.3.1",
    "ember-tooltip": "0.1.0",
    "ember-truth-helpers": "1.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-ember": "5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^3.14.1",
    "express": "4.14.0",
    "glob": "5.0.15",
    "http-proxy": "^1.16.2",
    "jison": "0.4.17",
    "morgan": "1.7.0",
    "multer": "1.2.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14"
  },
  "ember-addon": {
    "paths": [
      "lib/e-genesys"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js-rangeslider": "^1.2.1",
    "ember-cli-babel": "6.7",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "npm": "^6.0.1"
  }
```

Comment: Your upgrade of `ember-truth-helpers`didn't work for some reason.    
compare these folders:    
https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers/tree/v1.0.0/addon/utils
https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers/tree/v2.0.0/addon/utils
you can see that `register-helper.js` doesn't exist in `v2.0.0`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be relavant for `ember-truth-helpers` but in general you should upgrade ember addons by `ember install <addon-name>`. This command does two things: a) Adding/changing dependency in package.json and installing them via npm or yarn; b) running installation instructions of the addon defined in it's default blueprint. Since `ember-truth-helpers` does not have a default blueprint, this doesn't seem to be the issue here.